# Issue with .post() not reading properly

Tags: jquery

So I have a little linker that I am trying to make work, when the user enters their username and password it will connect to this site without actually leaving page but having some difficulty doing this.  I am using the .post() in jquery to send over to a aspx.page.

When I hit submit I get sent to the site and I don't want that, plus It wont sign in.

Code -

```
<div class="linkdimesAccount">



                    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="http://1betvegas.com/default.aspx" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_BtnSubmit')" id="aspnetForm" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
                if (!theForm) {
                    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
                }
                function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
                    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
                        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                        theForm.submit();
                    }
                }
                //]]>
                </script>
             <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="eYjk1H7gGdxNJmuevBY9L0vo1lS2NWgmApCJFEQznQr+AwZaPf/hYV4iGSnPCSknyHjESN/BgHueeChVuGgmN4wtWFCdUaYPJRItirNF0nIBHe9Q">
            </div>
            <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=FrT3YL7-WvrI_DKD4vsDo2d0Al_8j_u_HUym76C9Z5ggdJlIe1yu5cWI_jZDYcizjTU0SkefrocS8ATa0&amp;t=634604245351482412" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div>

                <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="yepc3zJ4Kjr5ru/aXm+s9SqYXyFoM+cwIlWPI69lDMnO4eybZJ1cM1pfzowM47Ggezne5505JNUx/VGe3XO8OCmvZnghqv8ZCuJm+yffjs4inz2n6ctjK/0F/qER0ARSznB8iJsMIZ7HxPXA/Stv+0ubH0U=">
            </div>
            <h2>Link your 5dimes account</h2>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <?php
                    if ($dimesaccount == 1){
                    echo "<h2 style='color:red;'> Please note your account is already linked.  If password or other information has changed please re-enter your username and password";
                    }
                    ?>
                        <td>
                        Username:
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_UserName" type="text" size="15" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin__UserName" accesskey="u" tabindex="60" class="login_input">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>
                        Password:
                        </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_IdBook" type="hidden" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin__IdBook">
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$Redir" type="hidden" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_Redir" value="wager/welcome.aspx">
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_Password" type="password" size="15" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin__Password" accesskey="p" tabindex="61" class="login_input">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$BtnSubmit" value="Link" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctlLogin_BtnSubmit" class="login_input" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
                    </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>


        </div><!-------.linkdimesAccount ------>
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#aspnetForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="__EVENTTARGET"]' ).val(),
        term1 = $form.find( 'input[name="__EVENTARGUMENT"]' ).val(),
        term2 = $form.find( 'input[name="__VIEWSTATE"]' ).val(),
        term3 = $form.find( 'input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_UserName"]' ).val(),
        term4 = $form.find( 'input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_IdBook"]' ).val(),
        term5 = $form.find( 'input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$Redir"]' ).val(),
        term6 = $form.find( 'input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$_Password"]' ).val(),
        term7 = $form.find( 'input[name="ctl00$MainContent$ctlLogin$BtnSubmit"]' ).val(),

        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.post( url, { s: term, s: term1, s: term2, s: term3, s: term4, s: term5, s: term6, s: term7 },
      function( data ) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to provide more information about the context beyond just jQuery and a mention of ASP (at least more appropriate tags).  There are other things affecting the JS.  The only immediate suggestion would be to try `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Yes, you would be denied by SOP...CORS could help if available or you have to do the full request.  Or you could do something like using an iframe which triggers an event in the top window.

Comment: I don't have access to this other site what so ever,  What would you recommend me doing?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you need to do, but without control over the other site you can't do it with in the browser with AJAX (security issue).  You can do it the old fashioned way, hack in an iframe, or use a server side reverse proxy to make the request from your server side code on behalf of the client (in order from least to most involved).

Comment: So what I need to do is - they have the ability to link there account to the app I'm making and make bids,  I want them to be able to stay on the site and it automaticly do that when they log in.  So should I use Iframe?

Comment: If you're accessing another secured site like that you'll need to use something like OAuth and an exposed API.  It sounds like you're looking to impersonate a user on another site, which should not be possible if the other site is properly secured (for what should be obvious reasons)

Comment: So unless I was able to get there access to do so I cant send the same url's etc.. to the site and acces?  Ultimately I am just sending info to the account like you would if you were actually logged onto it.

Comment: If the other site is properly secured then you will not be able to.  Even though your intentions may be good, that type of opening could be exploited for nefarious purposes.

Answer (score 0):

this caused by javascript error on your document that make your code is not working well.

for debug try to add `return false;` at the end of your code after post.
or try to set other button to fire submit. like

```
$("#someButtonButNutSubmit").click(function(){

var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="__EVENTTARGET"]' ).val(),
....

});
```

the check why your JavaScript/jQuery is failed. check browser console logs for detail